# What is a good choice for difference_type of counting iterators?

Tags: c++, stl

Due to being bored and wanting some practice (so, please don't tell me to [just use Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/iterator/doc/counting_iterator.html) :-) ) I am currently implementing a STL-style counting iterator.

However, while implementing functions that need `difference_type` to be defined to something meaningful, I found out that I don't know what should I actually use. At first I wanted to just use whatever type the iterator was templated with, but that leads to obvious problems with unsigned types, and just going "Whatever, I'll use `ptrdiff_t`", would lead to potential problems when templated with arbitrary-size integers.

Basically my question boils down to what should replace the `?` in the code below. (C++11 welcome, I am already using `static_assert`, `noexcept` specifiers and such)

```
template <typename Num>
class counting_iterator{
    typedef Num value_type;
    typedef counting_iterator<value_type> iter;
    typedef ? difference_type;

    /* Constructors, etc omitted for clarity */

    difference_type operator-(const iter& rhs) const {
        /* Calculate the difference here */
    }
};
```

Comment: I know you don't want me to just say "use Boost", but Boost does already have an answer to this question. There's `boost::detail::numeric_traits<T>::difference_type` or the user can override it. Strictly they get no guarantee if they don't specify the type, so you can make your equivalent as good or bad as you like. You could just use `int` when the user doesn't specify, and it's their own stupid fault for expecting better ;-)

Comment: If there's no real answer given no knowledge of Num, then let the client code specify the difference_type.  If you want to take a guess at it, use some kind of type traits (that way you can get an error if it's not known adequate, but clients can still add support for their own types easily) or if you're feeling lucky just pick e.g. int64_t as a default - it'll likely be ok 99.9% of the tme, and makes usage more convenient.

Comment: @SteveJessop I looked beforehand and from the docs, it it "Let the client code do it, or use non-specified default", which doesn't seem as that good an answer. (The non-specified part)

Comment: @Xarn: that's the thing, although the default isn't specified it isn't bad in fact. So how the Boost implementation actually does it is rather more useful than what the docs guarantee. If you deal with all the easier details then ultimately your problem is that there is (usually) no signed type able to express the difference between any two values of the largest unsigned type. And certainly not any difference of the largest signed type. This is a limitation of fixed-width types.

Comment: @SteveJessop Okay, I will probably go with another template argument + default of whatever ptrdiff_t is on given platform. (Oh and I don't have anything against "read through Boost better" answer. ;-) )

Comment: ... it occurs to me that you could define a template for fixed-width types, where the width is a template parameter. That is to say, make sure there is no "largest signed type", albeit they aren't integer types. Then `counting_iterator<Fixed<N>>::difference_type` could be `Fixed<N+1>`, and `counting_iterator<intmax_t>::difference_type` could be whatever `Fixed<N>` you need. But seriously ;-)

Comment: @SteveJessop I will rather just go with user-defined via template (+ sane default), thank you very much. ;-) Care to write it up as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Counting iterator is kind of a hack to begin with. The whole point of it is adding operator* to integer types. If that is really all they are for, then nobody cares what the difference_type is. 
If you want to get it right in any case than it should be the same type when Num is signed and a signed type with at least one more bit if Num is unsigned.

Should be something along these lines:

```
template <typename Num, bool IS_SIGNED>
class DifferenceType
{
public:
    typedef Num type;
};

template <unsigned DIGITS, bool DIGITS_32_OR_LESS>
class TypeLargerThanImp3
{
public:
    typedef int64 type;
};

template <unsigned DIGITS, bool DIGITS_16_OR_LESS>
class TypeLargerThanImp2
{
public:
    typedef int32 type;
};

template <unsigned DIGITS>
class TypeLargerThanImp2<DIGITS, false>
{
public:
    typedef TypeLargerThanImp3<DIGITS, (DIGITS<=32) >::type type;
};

template <unsigned DIGITS, bool DIGITS_8_OR_LESS>
class TypeLargerThanImp
{
public:
    typedef int16 type;
};

template <unsigned DIGITS>
class TypeLargerThanImp<DIGITS, false>
{
public:
    typedef TypeLargerThanImp2<DIGITS, (DIGITS<=16) >::type type;
};

template <unsigned DIGITS>
class TypeLargerThan
{
public:
    typedef TypeLargerThanImp<DIGITS, (DIGITS<=8) >::type type;
};

template <typename Num>
class DifferenceType<Num, false>
{
public:
    typedef TypeLargerThan<std::numeric_limits<Num>::digits>::type type;
};
```

And your difference type:

```
typedef DifferenceType<Num, std::numeric_limits<Num>::is_signed>::type difference_type;
```

Comment: Upvoted, but won't accept, because fixed width types just won't work for this. (See discussion)